# saml toolkit base64_decode failing

Tags: php, saml, onelogin

I have configured the Onelogin SAML Toolkit for PHP per the documentation. Sadly the output from base64_decode() function is incorrect.

I used the Onelogin Online decode and Inflate tool and get a correct value with same SAMLResponse.

SAML Assertions are signed, not encrypted per the IDP maintainer. IDP x509 certificate is correct in settings.

Where would I look next?

Comment: What binding is used to deliver `SAMLResponse` and **how** is the result of `base64_decode` incorrect? Does it yield gibberish, does it yield invalid XML, should it produce gzdeflated content.. some code and some output would help, especially this `SAMLResponse` that you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

The toolkit expects the SAMLResponse to be received at the ACS URL endpoint using the HTTP-POST binding, and base64 encoded (not deflated, so you dont need to decode and Inflate it).

I think that you are trying to process a SAMLResponse using the HTTP-Redirect binding that is not officially supported.